# How to export data from multiple .sql files in Folder to Excel in SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

I have many .sql files in a folder that contains SQL `SELECT` data with Data Result.  I wanna iterate all .sql files in my folder suppose I have 4 sql with all have `SELECT` statement.

How to Export it to Excel in each files using OLE DB Connections? I'm still confusing use variable in Foreach Loop Container in SSIS

Comment: Do you have direct access to the SQL database? Does the solution need to be in SSIS?

Comment: Yes I have an access to SQL Server database. No the solution not must have in SSIS. Do you have solution?

Comment: Probably can suggest a solution in VBA, not familiar with SSIS thou

Comment: I think I can build my application to export multiple files using .NET. But I still stuck with performance. And I prefer SSIS performance of handling so many data.

Comment: Has to  be in SSIS? The simplest solution would probably be to run BCP.EXE statements inside SSIS.

Comment: no.  what kind of solution do you have?